# How can a member function access member variables?

Tags: node.js

In the code snippet below I am trying to access name which is a member variable from sayHi which is a member function. How can I do that?

```
obj = {
    name:"John",
    sayHi: ()=>{
        console.log("Hi " + name);
    }

}
obj.sayHi();
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrow function expressions are best suited for non-method functions. It seems you want `sayHi` to use the `name` property of `obj`.
As such, you want to use `sayHi` as a method,
and in this case an arrow function is not appropriate for the purpose.

If you change the arrow function expression to an anonymous function,
then you can use `this.name` to refer to the `name` property of the object on which you will call the `sayHi` function:

```
obj = {
    name: "John",
    sayHi: function() {
        console.log("Hi " + this.name);
    }    
}
obj.sayHi();  // prints "Hi John"
```

A good resource about arrow function expressions is this page on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: @WaterfrVilla In your environment `this` is `undefined` when used in an arrow function expression. This can happen for example in strict mode. It's a safety feature. You should not use `this` in arrow function expressions, they were not designed for this use case.

Comment: @WaterfrVilla do you need more help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use an anonymous function like @janos says. When you're using arrow functions, `this` refers to the class or context that your object is defined in. So you can call into name by calling `this.obj.name` like so:

```
obj = {
    name:"John",
    sayHi: ()=>{
        console.log("Hi " + this.obj.name);
    }

}
obj.sayHi();
```

Comment: did not work! same error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: btw my bad, I had to mention that my script is in nodejs. what you suggested might work for js

Comment: This only works if you assign to `this.obj` instead of `obj`. But even then, only if `this` is defined in the original context. Furthermore, this answer tries to answer a question about the implicit `this` context of functions vs arrow functions... by introducing another unrelated implicit `this` context.